IQ Mismatch and Image-II
I asked the question IQ Mismatch and Image about the relationship between IQ mismatch and image signals in an IQ transmitter. The accepted answer says that the in-phase component (with amplitude A in Dan's answer) and quadrature component (with amplitude B in Dan's answer) should match in amplitude (\$|A| = |B|\$) and phase (\$\angle A - \angle B = 90^\circ\$) to avoid the image. But in a 16 QAM constellation, for instance, we can have symbols that could inevitably make A not equal to B. Does that mean we would have an image signal for a 16 QAM signal or in general any N-QAM signal (N > 4), no matter how well-matched the circuit is, just because of the nature of the signal itself? For example, consider a 16 QAM signal constellation below:

If we transmit the symbol 0010, the I signal is greater in amplitude compared to the Q signal, would it not generate an image?

With a quadrature modulated signal such as QAM we can have conditions where the amplitude of the “I” and “Q” components are not matched but this does not indicate an image issue. For example consider if we always transmitted the symbol 0110 in the OP’s question, for that it is clear that “I” will be significantly larger than “Q” when the signal is centered at baseband (with no carrier or phase offsets). To note the spectrum will only consist of a complex DC tone since it is not changing with time. We can also envision other scenarios where there is only a positive frequency component (such as if we sequentially chose symbols that consistently rotated counter-clockwise around the constellation). The result will be one sided, but that doesn’t mean there is an image issue as the result represents the desired symbols exactly (no interference or distortion). The following diagrams summarizing the Fourier relationships may help visualize this:

If we then introduced a quadrature or amplitude error in the generation of those symbols, then an image problem would appear in that we would also see a smaller (assuming small errors) component in the negative frequency as well. This image is not the intended or expected spectrum and in the general case of a 2 sided modulated waveform where the positive and negative sides are independent, these images become interference signals reducing SNR, EVM or other signal quality metrics.

It appears from the plot that the case for the phasor that isn't changing (DC) that nothing has occurred in the frequency domain. However this is to show that the issue from the quadrature or amplitude error is not just that it creates images in the other sideband - what is shown in the plots above in the frequency domain is the magnitude of the frequency result only, however the phase has also changed due to the quadrature error that has resulted! This distortion would be easier to visualize in the time domain in that we wish to be at a specific magnitude and phase in the constellation but due to the quadrature error the actual magnitude and phase will be in error, resulting in a distortion quantified as "Error Vector Magnitude" (EVM) as the rms error of all the errors from our actual locations in the constellation to the ideal locations. Here as plotted in the time domain due to a quadrature error on the Q-axis specifically, our projection onto the I axis will not have changed, but the projection onto Q will be larger making the angle appear larger than it's actual position (an resulting in an error vector!).
That said, assuming we have equiprobable data, then we CAN use a longer term correlation of I to Q to make an estimate of and correct for quadrature error, and similarly a longer term estimate of the magnitude of I compared the the magnitude of Q (the rms level specifically) to estimate and correct for amplitude error. Data whitening that is commonly done is helpful for implementing this common correction technique. When there is an actual quadrature error (as could occur in “Zero-IF” receivers), some of the I signal will leak to Q and vice versa, so the correlation measures this leakage very effectively, and the amount of leakage scaled to the overall magnitude will equal the quadrature error in radians assuming small angle conditions (when $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$).
